Limit MongoDB Database Size/Quota
I'm running the latest version on Docker(Mongodb server 7.0.11), and I'd like to know: Are there any mechanisms to limit the size of a single database on MongoDB? Or perhaps a way to impose a storage quota on a particular user?

Have you tried to use the parameters --smallfiles and --quotafiles in conjunction with -quota?

@M.Behrens , I saw that on an old post( link ), but that would rather affect the server instance globally, and besides, it has one other shortcoming, what if I wanted to delegate different sizes/quotas to different databases/users?

There are Capped Collections (in MongoDB a set of collections make a database). These allow fixed-size collections.

@prasad_ , seems not to work with gridfs collections. It shows the ".chunks" collection as "capped": true, and "maxSize" as I set with "convertToCapped"(to 32 megabytes), "max" : -1, however I can still keep adding stuff, and it will not put on the breaks. The "size" property stopped increasing very closed to the value I set as "maxSize", just shy of surpassing it, however, "storageSize" keeps increasing as I add more files(It's close to 50 megabytes and the bucket keeps accepting new files).

May be it doesn't work well with GridFS (see Is it possible to Cap a GridFS collection?). You may want to add more details about your requirement / question so that you could get more responses.

@prasad_ , yes, it seems it doesn't work as one would imagine with GridFS. I believe MongoDB has support for triggers/events, right? Maybe coding with "db.collection.watch();" / "Change Streams", I could watch for an insert event(or it's MongoDB equivalent) and check "db.files.chunks.stats();" for the "size" property, and throw an error in case it doesn't conform to max size information stored elsewhere.  I shall post my findings, once I get enough time do try it.

Change streams requires that your deployment is a replica-set.

How about limiting the size of the docker volume like this?
